# New Checkout of Visual Studio C# Project Missing Files of Last Commit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2013, tortoisesvn

I am working in a c# visual studio project. My Visual studio version is Visual studio MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I have connected my source code with SVN. My TortoiseSVN version is 1.9.5, Build 27581 - 64 Bit , 2016/11/26 09:18:58. 
I added some form controllers and some crystal report controllers to my project and committed successfully. Then I got a new checkout to a new folder. Then I tried to build the project. It showed many errors due to missing files. Some of the missing files were the files I added in previous commit. Others were some old files. 
I had to right click on each file and had to select add to source to get rid of the errors. 
The missing files were shown in the solution explorer as in the below image.

[image]

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Look in the Subversion log itself. Were these files added to Subversion at the time you committed? Unless you have a VS plugin that's handling your all of your version control and doesn't require that you manually add new project artifacts before committing, you need to explicitly `svn add` them before committing.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio we donot need to add dll or exe files in TortoiseSVN. All said files might be in the bin folder of project which is excluded from project. These files are auto generated by Visual Studio on Successful Build of project.
**NOTE:**Just add the reference of your dll and exe files in your Visual Studio project   as shown in the screen shot below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8tLc.png)